# Weakly square summable series as operators on Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $H$ such that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}|\langle h,a_n\rangle|^2<\infty$ for all $h\in H$. Here $\langle\dot{},\dot{}\rangle$ denotes the inner product on $H$ and such a series is called weakly square summable.

Such a sequence defines an operator $T\colon H\to l^2$, $h\mapsto \{\langle h,a_n\rangle\}$.

How can I show that this is a continuous operator?

Also, is there an example of a weakly square summable sequence that is not square summable, i.e. $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}|\langle h,a_n\rangle|^2<\infty$ for all $h$ but $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}||a_n||^2=\infty$?

Comment: I try an elementary argument : suppose $H = l^2$. there two ways for $ T : l^2 \to l^2$ to be unbounded :  $\|T \delta_n\| = \|a_n\|$ is unbounded, or there is an unitary operator $U : l^2 \to l^2$ such that $\|TU\delta_n\|$  is unbounded. then if $\|a_n\|$ is unbounded it is easy to see that $\|T h\|$ can't be finite for every $h$, and the argument is the same for showing that  $\|TU\delta_n\|$ can't be unbounded, because otherwise $\| T U (U^* h)\|$ wouldn't be finite for every $h$.

Answer (score 1):

The Closed Graph Theorem shows easily that $T$ is bounded.

Hint for the second question: There's a result you know very well that says that if the sequence $(a_n)$ is a ... then $(a_n)$ is weakly square summable. (The statement of this result that you've seen does not use that terminology, but that's what it says.)

Comment: Of course, an orthonomal basis is weakly square summable but not square summable.
But about the first part: this was the hint in the exercise as well but it is not obvious to me that the graph of $T$ must be closed. Can you explain how to see that?

Comment: It is very easy. "Show us what you've done so far"....